# gcloud auth print-access-token gives permission denied error

Tags: bash, shell, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a shell script trying to download some secrets from secret manager inside dataproc cluster.

```
    GetAuthJson() {
  authjson=$(curl "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/$AUTH_JSON/versions/1:access" \
    --request "GET" \
    --header "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    --header "content-type: application/json")
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    Error "Unable to extract the $PIPENAME Auth json details from GCP Secret Manager"
  fi

  echo $authjson | grep -o '"data": "[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$' >$BASE_DIR/encodedauth.json
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    Error "Unable to save the $PIPENAME auth.json server secret to auth.json"
  fi

  auth_json=$(base64 -d $BASE_DIR/encodedauth.json)
  base64 -d $BASE_DIR/encodedauth.json >/etc/secrets/auth.json

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    Error "Unable to decode the $PIPENAME auth.json server secret"
  fi
  Log "auth.json secret extraction done"
}
```

when i run this curl it generates an error

```
authjson='{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission '\''secretmanager.versions.access'\'' denied for resource '\''projects/**-**-dev/secrets/**_AUTH_JSON/versions/1'\'' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}'
```

the same curl with same service account is working in local meachine. and more over if i copy the CURL from local and run it in dataproc cluster it works as well.
But the curl generated from dataproc fails in local .

whats more weird is if i run gcloud auth print-access-token separately and paste it in curl command it works in both meachine.

so my question is why gcloud auth print-access-token generated as part of curl in dataproc cluster is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you could capture the value of the `curl` command or, at least the value of `gcloud auth print-access-token` that's failing in the script.

I suspect (I'm unfamiliar with Dataproc) that the Dataproc instance does not have `gcloud` installed and the `gcloud auth print-access-token` is failing.

If the instance does have `gcloud` installed, since it's running then it must have a Service Account and so should permit authenticating. There may (!?) be a more nuanced issue with getting an access token as a Dataproc instance, unclear.

Please consider using either [`gcloud secrets versions access`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/versions/access) directly or one of Google's client libraries to [access the secret](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#access).

You're making the process more complex than it need be by `curl`'ing the endpoint; you're having to use `gcloud` anyway to get the auth token.

Comment: i tried running  gcloud auth print-access-token separately and placed inside CURL and it works.. it is only when the CURL is generated from script it fails with permission error . so i am confident its not an issue with cluster or any scope of gcloud. it is something else..

Comment: i need the auth.json in a separate directory .,thats why i has to download again even though i already have service account enabled with it.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use `gcloud secrets version access` in your script instead of using `gcloud print-access-token` and passing the result to a curl command that attempts to mirror `gcloud secrets access version`.

Comment: What I wanted to understand is whether you can separate e.g. `local TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) && echo ${TOKEN}` from `curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN} ...`. If you get a valid token from the first command and it works when passed to `curl` if it is **functionalliy equivalent** to combining the two comamnds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i ran the script as sudo user. When i ran normally it worked.